# Ruby - How to skip 2 lines after reading a blank line from file

Tags: ruby, lines, skip

I have this loop:

```
File.open(path_to_file, "r") do |infile|
  infile.each_line do |line|
   #do things with line
  end
end
```

And what I want to do:
If the current line is blank "/^[\s]*$\n/" skip the next 2 lines and continue reading from there.

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to solve the problem, rather than write code to fill in the blanks. Please read "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. How big is the file? What is the minimum example of the file that will demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For such situation, I would do something like this:

```
file = File.open(path_to_file, "r")

while !file.eof?
  line = file.gets
  if line.match(/^[\s]*$\n/)
    2.times{ file.gets if !file.eof? }
  else
    # do something with line
  end
end
```

Comment: It's worth noting here that `\A` and `\z` are preferable to `^` and `$` since the latter are anchored to lines, the former the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a test file.

```
str =
" \nNow is \nthe time \n \nfor all \ngood \npeople \n\nto \nsupport\na nasty\n \nperson\n" 
puts str
  # 
  # Now is  
  # the time 
  # 
  # for all 
  # good 
  # people 
  #
  # to 
  # support
  # a nasty
  # 
  # person
  #=> nil 

FName = "almost_over"

IO.write(FName, str)
  #=> 75
```

Let's confirm the file was written correctly.

```
IO.read(FName) == str
  #=> true
```

We can skip the unwanted lines as follows.

```
count = 0
IO.foreach(FName) do |line|
  if count > 0
    count -=1
  elsif line.strip.empty?
    count = 2
  else
    puts "My code using the line '#{line.strip}' goes here"
  end
end
  # My code using the line 'people' goes here
  # My code using the line 'a nasty' goes here
  #=> nil
```

As [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html) is a subclass of [IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html) (`File < IO #=> true`), you will often see expressions using `IO` methods with `File` as the receiver (e.g., `File.read(FName)`).